# Geth - How to clear queued transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions

When typing txpool on Geth I get:

```
{ 
  status: {
    pending: 15,
    queued: 714
  },
  getStatus: function()
}
```

I don't even know why there are 714 queued transactions when there should be none. I guess I messed something up.

More importantly, my wallet just sent a week-old transaction to my kraken.com deposit that didn't go through at the time due to whatever reason but did now that I had sufficient ether.

How can I clear the transaction queue to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: I was under the impression that the transaction queue gets cleared each time you shut down / restart geth. Have you tried that?

Comment: @tayvano no, it isn't. I'm trying to cope with it right now - I have hundreds of transactions somewhere in queue unsent, that's not the txpool queue, geth restart / update to latest version did not help.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not a great solution, but it works:

1. Exit geth
2. Delete your `geth/transactions.rlp` file
3. Restart geth and pending transactions should be empty (running `eth.pendingTransactions` outputs `[]`)

Comment: What does this do? Are the pending transactions braodcasted to network, or they are just lost?

Comment: restart geth dosen't delete queued transactions

Answer (score 13):

> Queued transactions are transactions where the transaction nonce is
>   not in sequence. The transaction nonce is an incrementing number for
>   each transaction with the same From address.
>
> For example:
>
> - Transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonce 0 has been included
>     in the blockchain.
> - Transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonce 1
>     has been included in the blockchain.
> - 10 transactions from account
>     0xaaaa...aaaa with nonces 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 as sent to
>     an Ethereum node. These are placed in the transaction queue as the
>     transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa with nonce 2 has not been seen
>     by the Ethereum node.
> - **Once the transaction from account 0xaaaa...aaaa
>     with nonce 2 is added to the transaction pool, the 10 transactions
>     with nonces 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 and 12 will be moved from the
>     queue to the pending transaction pool and all 11 transactions are
>     ready to be processed and inserted into into the blockchain** (provided
>     there is enough gas).

[What is the max size of transactions can clients like geth keep in txpool?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/what-is-the-max-size-of-transactions-can-clients-like-geth-keep-in-txpool)

Comment: good explanation helps, but this doesn't answer the question of how to clear them up (cancel them)

Comment: how to clear queued transactions or cancel them ? (after a period of time or number)