# personal_sendTranaction for token tranfer return hash but transaction isn't found in the blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, tokens

I am using Geth as a provider to the blockchain. I perform JSON-RPC method send_Transaction to transfer tokens, it returns me hash of the transaction but I can't see this transaction in the Etherscan. 
When I call method eth_getTransactionByHash, it return result: "blockHash":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","blockNumber":null. Geth logs don't show any errors.

Transaction with same parameters are succesufully sent before.
When I try to send similar transaction into Ropsten blockchain, all do succesfull.

Comment: Make sure your nonce is correct. If you try to reuse an old nonce, the tx will be dropped

Comment: All transactions nonces are incremented correctly and all of them have unique value.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue.

I sent a transaction with a too low gasPrice before (0x3). It hung and was't confirmed. Then other transactions that I sent after just put into queue and can't be proceed because in the etherium blockchain transaction can't be proceed while transaction with a previous nonce don't confirmed.

To resolve this issue you just need to clear all queued transactions, as are written in this topic :
[Geth - How to clear queued transactions?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1774/geth-how-to-clear-queued-transactions)

Comment: You should choose this answer, otherwise @Community will bump this question on top again and again.